# Testing File uploads in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, file-upload, phpunit, integration-testing, functional-testing

In the Symfony2 documentation it gives the simple example of:

```
$client->request('POST', '/submit', array('name' => 'Fabien'), array('photo' => '/path/to/photo'));
```

To simulate a file upload.

However in all my tests I am getting nothing in the $request object in the app and nothing in the `$_FILES` array.

Here is a simple `WebTestCase` which is failing. It is self contained and tests the request that the `$client` constructs based on the parameters you pass in. It's not testing the app.

```
class UploadTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function testNewPhotos() {
        $client = $this->createClient();
        $client->request(
            'POST', 
            '/submit', 
            array('name' => 'Fabien'), 
            array('photo' => __FILE__)
        );

        $this->assertEquals(1, count($client->getRequest()->files->all()));
    }
}
```

**Just to be clear.** This is not a question about how to do file uploads, that I can do. It is about how to test them in Symfony2.

**Edit**

I'm convinced I'm doing it right. So I've created a test for the Framework and made a pull request.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/1891

Comment: I think that this question should be closed or mark as answered, I've follow this conversation: github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/1891 and it seems that was just a problem with documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was an error in the documentation.

Fixed [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/commit/e6027eb):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

$photo = new UploadedFile('/path/to/photo.jpg', 'photo.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 123);
// or
$photo = array('tmp_name' => '/path/to/photo.jpg', 'name' => 'photo.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg', 'size' => 123, 'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK);

$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/submit', array('name' => 'Fabien'), array('photo' => $photo));
```

Documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code which works with Symfony 2.3 (I didn't tried with another version):

I created an `photo.jpg` image file and put it in `Acme\Bundle\Tests\uploads`.

Here is an excerpt from `Acme\Bundle\Tests\Controller\AcmeTest.php`:

```
function testUpload()
{
    // Open the page
    ...

    // Select the file from the filesystem
    $image = new UploadedFile(
        // Path to the file to send
        dirname(__FILE__).'/../uploads/photo.jpg',
        // Name of the sent file
        'filename.jpg',
        // MIME type
        'image/jpeg',
        // Size of the file
        9988
    );

    // Select the form (adapt it for your needs)
    $form = $crawler->filter('input[type=submit]...')->form();

    // Put the file in the upload field
    $form['... name of your field ....']->upload($image);

    // Send it
    $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

    // Check that the file has been successfully sent
    //  (in my case the filename is displayed in a <a> link so I check
    //  that it appears on the page)
    $this->assertEquals(
        1,
        $crawler->filter('a:contains("filename.jpg")')->count()
    );
}
```

Comment: on the created UploadedFile object $file->isValid() fails. any idea why?

Comment: @astroanu please add a new question to explain your problem.

Comment: Still works on Symfony 5.0, except the `UploadedFile` constructor removes the file size and added **error** & **test**.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the question is related to Symfony2, it appears in the top results when searching for Symfony4 in Google.

Instancing an `UploadedFile` works, but the shortest way I found was also actually in the official documentation:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/post/hello-world');
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('submit');
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
$form['photo']->upload('/path/to/lucas.jpg');
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#forms

Answer (score 1):

I found this article, https://coderwall.com/p/vp52ew/symfony2-unit-testing-uploaded-file, and works perfect.

Regards

Comment: this is a much better solution. Unit test where you can!

Comment: Please include the code in your answer so your answer will be still valid if the page disappear.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to mock a UploadedFile without a client request, you can use:

```
    $path = 'path/to/file.test';
    $originalName = 'original_name.test';
    $file = new UploadedFile($path, $originalName, null, UPLOAD_ERR_OK, true);
    $testSubject->method($file);
```

Comment: The fifth parameter active the "test" mode, in order to not trigger HTTP real upload in test.