# Symfony functional tests: receive uploaded file

Tags: testing, symfony, upload, phpunit

I have an HTML form which contains the following input: `<input type="file" name="sentFile" />`
The form has NOT been generated with `$this->createFormBuilder()`. I have written a class that `extends WebTestCase`. Its testing method does the following:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/users/import');
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('Import');
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
$testfile = 'import_users.csv';
$destination = 'F:/www/symfony/web/uploads/' . $testfile;
$form['sentFile']->upload($destination);
$form['myparam'] = 'hello';
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

But when I run the test with the `phpunit` command, the controller method which receives the posted form shows an empty `$_FILES`. The other input (`myparam`) is correctly received. So how can use the uploaded file?

PS:

- I have not succeeded to use PHPT in Symfony (stackoverflow.com/questions/4922207/integrate-phpt-test-cases-with-phpunit/4925061).
- I have not tried Selenium yet

References:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html
- [Testing File uploads in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916989/testing-file-uploads-in-symfony2)
- http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Request.html#method_getFiles
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

Comment: Would call to $request->files->keys() return anything in your controller?

Comment: Thank you Jakub, this solved my problem! I didn't know about this property. So I received this UploadedFile object and requested its properties to map the ones of $_FILE that I used previously in my file processing code.

Comment: Just wanted to ask if keepign an absolute path `'F:/www/symfony/web/uploads/'` for the uplaod directory is a good practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `$_FILES` does not seems to be changeable to simulate a file upload, so a solution is to use the http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html class. As Jakub said, when a form is submitted the way I wrote in my question, the `Request` object of the controller is filled with this content, so we can use $request->files->get('sentFile') to get the `UploadedFile` that corresponds to the file sent via the `sentFile` input of the form.

Comment: Exactly. Always use Symfony abstractions from the HttpFoundation over global variables.